# Date and Time Conversion in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, date

I am currently looking on converting `Thu Jun 10 16:17:55 +0530 2010` to `15/06/2010` or `15-06-2010` using Ruby

I am getting the dates from the DB as shown below.

```
   @tickets = Ticket.find(:all)
   for ticket in @tickets
     print ticket.created_at
   end
```

I have been looking around for resources as I a n00b in RoR/Ruby.

> I have looked at
>
> - [Class Date](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Date.html)
> - [Class DateTime](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/DateTime.html#M002791)

and couldn't make much of it.

Please let me know how I could achieve this conversion in Ruby.

P.S: I have tried using regular expressions as well. But with no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this.

```
   @tickets = Ticket.find(:all)
   for ticket in @tickets
     print ticket.created_at.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
   end
```

For complete reference of strftime see [here](http://www.nullislove.com/2007/05/16/time-for-strftime/)

Comment: But I get `undefined method `strftime' for #<Ticket:0x488c97c>` on doing this? Am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks much! Noticed you did an edit and it is working fine for me :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Rails (which is indicated by your tag)

Date.today.to_s can take a parameter which represents a key in your DATE_FORMATS hash

- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Date/Conversions.html#M000915
- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Time/Conversions.html#M000837

A much better solution than #strftime, since its reusable without having to remember the #strftime incantation or having loads of helpers to do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks much! I shall check this out

Answer (score 1):

```
@tickets = Ticket.find(:all)
for ticket in @tickets
  print ticket.created_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
end
```

Also you may want to check out the `strftime` method in [Ruby's stdlib](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/).